# Python match content with its file name

Tags: python

I have files with Lisa.txt, Depp.txt and John.txt each. Inside the txt file is the list of subjects enrolled in the semester. Ex in Lisa.txt:

```
Algebra AccountingII
```

I have created a code that helps to gather the file names and its contents into the following format:

```
Lisa.txt Algebra
Lisa.txt AccountingII
Depp.txt Finance
Depp.txt Algebra 
Depp.txt Community 
John.txt Algebra 
John.txt AlgebraII 
John.txt Community
```

The code:

```
for file in glob("*.txt"): 
    f = open(file, "r")
    for word in f: 
        word_l = word.lower().strip().split()
        for i in word_l:
            text = process_word(i)
            print('%s\t%s' % (file, text))
```

How could I achieve the output such that:

```
Algebra (Lisa Depp John)
AccountingII (Lisa John)
Community (Depp John)
```

Comment: What does `process_word` look like?

Comment: You can use dictionary where `key` will be subject and `value` will be `list` of name. And while storing iterate this dictionary and store it in desired format. You can get `key` and `value` from dictionary with [`.items()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary using the subjects as keys and the list of associated file names as values. Then print the key and values.

```
name_to_subject_map = {'Algebra': [] , 'AccountingII': [], 'Community':[]}

for file in glob("*.txt"): 
    f = open(file, "r")
    for word in f: 
        word_l = word.lower().strip().split()
        for i in word_l:
            text = process_word(i)
            person_name = file.replace('.txt', '')
            if person_name not in name_to_subject_map[text]:
                name_to_subject_map[text].append(person_name)

for key, val in name_to_subject_map.items():
    print(key, values)
```

That should give you an output like :

```
Algebra [Lisa, Depp, John]
AccountingII [Lisa, John]
Community [Depp, John]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a dictionary to map subjects to unique students in those subjects.  You can use a defaultdict to manage some of the tedium for you

```
from collections import defaultdict
from glob import glob

d = defaultdict(set)

for fname in glob('*.txt'):
    name, ext = fname.split('.')
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.strip().split():
                d[word].add(name)

for word, names in d.items():
    print(word, names)
```